# How to implement a Webservice Connection from AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: android, rest

I've got a Problem.

I'm working on this since hours without result:

```
    public void getData(){

    new Task().execute();


}

class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... noargs) {
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=True%20Grit&y=1969");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            StringBuffer zeile = new StringBuffer("");

            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
                zeile.append(line);
            }

            String res = zeile.toString();

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Everytime (the getDate() is called by a button) I get an exception and on my phone it says that "Unfortunately the app was finished". Do yout know where my mistake is?

The Exception is a: NetworkOnMainThreadException, how can I solve it?

Thank U so much!

Answer (score 1):

You should move all network related code to `doInBackground()` and process the result of the network call inside `onPostExecute()`. Here's how your code should look like:

```
class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... noargs) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=True%20Grit&y=1969");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            StringBuffer zeile = new StringBuffer("");

            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
                zeile.append(line);
            }

            String res = zeile.toString();
            return res;  
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onPostExecute()` and `onPreExecute()` of the async task run on the UI thread. Move the network code from your `onPostExecute()` to `doInBackground()`.